# Wiring for Internet of Things

Tags: home-automation

I'm interested in home automation and the Internet of Things and what options presently exist in the relatively cutting-edge field.

I would like to know if it is possible to use something like a central home computer (equivalent to ECUs in vehicles) that is connected to the internet and which can, for example, flip power switches without the need that the switch itself has a CPU and modem to connect to the internet directly, like the Nest thermostat does (which makes it bigger, more complicated and expensive). In order to do that, the electric (Romex) NM cable that is normally 14/2 NM (hot, neutral, and ground), that connects the switch, would also need to have data wires or cable to correspond with the computer, which, I'm guessing should be close to or better yet integrated in the main electrical panel.

The above paragraph is something between a fantasy guess and an educated hypothesis. I'm asking if what I described exists or is on its way or am I missing how the whole thing should work.

Comment: Home automation is a huge subject and I don't think this is a good question for this site unless you can narrow it down to some specific task you need to do. You might find some ideas about how do do some automation over at the [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites. There are also off-the-shelf switches and controllers available that would let you do some automation (over existing power lines) without building anything yourself - search for Z-Wave or Insteon products for examples.

Comment: My specific question is what kind of wiring is used

Comment: You can use your existing home wiring, no need for special wiring for control signals. Systems like Z-Wave and Insteon (those are just a couple examples, there are others) work by sending signals over your home wiring (and/or wireless signals). If you really want to have dedicated control wiring, there are systems for that too (generally used for commercial applications).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of particular products or solutions, but I will say that hardwiring any of it is quickly becoming obsolete. Technology will advance which will downsize the products and make everything more convenient. Right now there are already the Belkin switches that fit in a regular switch box, connect over wifi and with existing electrical wires, and can be controlled through a phone instead of a desktop computer or  set interface.

As mentioned before, anything can be done if you throw enough money at it. But honestly, it's actually cheaper now-a-days to get the convenient stuff.

And back towards your example, that can all be done with programmable logic and some relays to create a whole home system that can be rewired at will without the need for any internet connection. Again though, this isn't exactly cheap.

Comment: My only question about the thought that hardwiring becoming obsolete is, what happens when every house on every block has wifi for every switch, light, thermostat, TV, etc. Wireless is not as reliable as wire so does this become unworkable at some point. It's something I've not taken much time to think about.

Comment: @Rob Yes, there is interference among wifi when you have so much of it - like at apartment buildings currently. There are multiple channels that wifi can run on to help alleviate this, but it still limits how many you can have. - I had a friend in an apartment paying for 100mbps internet, but only able to get 3-5mbps standing next to his router because there were so many signals around. Running internet cables from the router gave him the full 100mbps, but that was the only way. However, a single family neighborhood should never have any issue like this.

Comment: @Rob So really hardwiring anything will typically provide better results, but it's more of a process to set up. It'll never go obsolete, but it won't be used for most setups.

Comment: You're stating my point. It won't matter what people want to do. There is a limit at the moment that may keep this from working for many people. Maybe it can and will be solved but it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I hope you have some time to devote to this.

This area has exploded in recent years with everybody and their mom getting into it.

Basically you can do anything you have the desire (and money) to do.

Here is just one web site of a group that has an open source agnostic home automation system.

http://www.openhab.org

Get youself an Arduino or RaspberryPi and start learning.

The adventure begins!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve this "the old way", with some kind of centralized switching.

Today, what you are calling in your post "CPU and modem" is typically accomplished by the addition of what has become VERY inexpensive microprocessors and single-chip radio transceivers.  There are several examples of this even in the realm of devices for makers and hackers to use for experimental purposes that can provide both the "smarts" and the internet connectivity for a single device...for less than $10.

With the price of that part of the system so low, and always dropping...it is no longer more cost efficient or desirable to "centralize" a home automation system.

These days the push is to create a network of partially autonomous devices that all communicate with each other and with centralized human interfaces.

In short...wires are "old school".  (and not in a good way)

Comment: That's why I was asking if my hypothesis was right

Answer (score 0):

For IoT applications (Internet of Things) no new wires will be required.  Most devices use WiFi radio, or a wireless mesh network like Bluetooth or Zigbee or Z-Wave.

For conventional home control Insteon is a brand of home automation products that runs signals over the existing house wiring.

Only a few high speed signals, like those for a PC or video streaming for cameras, really benefit from having wires any more.